# TextView Html formatting

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textview which should render its content with HTML formatting. From code, this can be achieved like this,

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(someText));
```

Is there a way to do this through the XML?

I ask because i do not want to set the text through the code, In my case, the text comes from a DB call and displayed through an adapter.

Comment: What kind of formatting? What does the text look like?

Comment: @Robby Pond,

Hi, the text looks like this - 

&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: trebuchet ms,geneva;&quot;&gt;(Day 1) Typically we obtain 1200 mouse islets from 12 Cd1 mice. The  isolation is done by the UVA Islet Isolation Core. Islets are delivered  to us in RPMI + P/S + 10% FBS with 25 mm Glucose (which is prepared by  us and given to the islet core lab).&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: trebuchet ms,geneva;

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are a bunch of (simple) tags that are understood by TextView -- if the text is set in XML from a string resource.

So basically

```
<TextView text="@string/foo" .. />
```

It is also possible to give templates like `"Hello <b>%s</b>"`, but here you still need to run some code to fill in the value for `%s`

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html for formatting hints and short examples.

Comment: in this case, the text is not set from a string resource, but from a db call - the text is something like this 

&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: trebuchet ms,geneva;&quot;&gt;(Day 1) Typically we obtain 1200 mouse islets from 12 Cd1 mice. The  isolation is done by the UVA Islet Isolation Core. Islets are delivered  to us in RPMI + P/S + 10% FBS with 25 mm Glucose (which is prepared by  us and given to the islet core lab).&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: trebuchet ms,geneva;